# Quantile regression plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how I can bring these information into a plot to show the quantile curve at 0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975.

```
library(quantreg)
data(engel)
attach(engel)
qs <- c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)
cubic.rq <- rq(foodexp ~ poly(income, 3),qs, engel)
f <- coef(cubic.rq)
```

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41842/what-are-the-red-lines-in-quantile-regression-plot-quantreg-package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For comparison, I've included the linear regression line (for a third-order polynomial fit) and the data points as well.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantreg)
data(engel)

qs <- c(0.025,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.975)

ggplot(engel, aes(income, foodexp)) +
  geom_point(size=1, colour="grey70") +
  geom_quantile(quantiles=qs, formula=y ~ poly(x, 3), colour="red") +
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula=y ~ poly(x,3), colour="blue", 
              se=FALSE, linetype="11") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks so much, just a question. you set method="lm", should I change it to method="rq"?

Comment: The `geom_smooth` statement is just for drawing the blue "standard" linear regression line and has nothing to do with quantile regression. It's just there for comparison. The quantile regression lines are drawn by `geom_quantile`.